# How can I enforce this relationship? (Formerley: Is there a name for this type of database structure?)

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-5

**Update 05/15/2013**
My understanding of the problem has changed such that my "Title" doesn't match anymore. Should I close this and start a new post? (What is the proper way to handle an edit like this in the StackOverflow community?).

With the following basic table structure, how can I enforce a relationship where a `User` can be a member of a `Group`, but only if the `User` and `Group` are both related to the same `Tenant`?

**Entities:**

- **Tenants**:

  - ID
  - Name
- **User**

  - ID
  - fkTenantID
  - Name
- **Groups**

  - ID
  - fkTenantID
  - Name
- **UsersInGroup**

  - fkUserID
  - fkGroupID

**For example:**

I add 2 `Tenants`:

**ID: Name**

1: TenantA

2: TenantB

I add 1 `Group` to each `Tenant`:

**ID: TenantID: Name**

1: 1: GroupA

2: 2: GroupB

I add 1 `User` to TenantA having ID of 1:

**ID: TenantID: UserName**

1: 1: UserA

How can I restrict it so that I can not add UserA to GroupB.

If I create a table `UsersInGroups` with columns fkUserID, fkGroupID, I can't think of a way to constrain it so that a record like 1:2 would be considered invalid.

Thanks!

Steve

Comment: Thanks Marc, obviously you are correct. I need to spend more time reviewing before posting.

Comment: Relationships, constraints, dependencies... I'd pick up a book on SQL Server because there are alot of terms related to what you're asking

Comment: Hi J Lo, Thanks! I don't think I represented the problem I am trying to solve or my level of understanding and experience with SQL Server. I'm going to edit the question, have a second look in a bit if you have time.